# Not able select month from dropdown in google sign up page using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select a month from the Google sign up page using Selenium.
Below is my code:

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth"))).build().perform();
//clicking and holding the month dropdown         
WebElement menuElement=driver.findElement(By.id(":7"));

action.moveToElement(menuElement).click();
```

But it's not selecting the desired month.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `perform()` in the `click()`

```
action.moveToElement(menuElement).click().perform();
```